# How to use custom 404 page on not found controller/action

Tags: zend-framework, http-status-code-404

I have wrote a custom `404 Page Not Found` page. 
But where I have to put it in my Zend Application structure and how to show it?

When a controller couldn't be found I receive an `Invalid controller specified (dsa)` error. 
And when an action couldn't be found I receive an `Action "wqe" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()` error.

Shortly, I don't want these errors.

How can I detect if the page is not found before rendering? And when I detect it, how can I show my custom error page. At the moment I receive the errors from above but the layout is still displayed.

Do I need some `.htaccess` rules? Or it can be done with some Zend stuff.

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://dionysus.uraganov.net/frameworks/custom-error-pages-in-zend-framework/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your ErrorController

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

  public function errorAction() {
    $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

    if (!$errors || !$errors instanceof ArrayObject) {
      $this->view->message = 'You have reached the error page';
      return;
    }

    switch ($errors->type) {
      case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
      case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
      case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
        // 404 error -- controller or action not found
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
        $priority = Zend_Log::NOTICE;
        $this->view->error_code = $this->getResponse()->getHttpResponseCode();
        $this->view->message = "Page Not Found";
        $this->renderScript('error/error_404.phtml');
        break;
      default:
        // application error
        print_r($this->getResponse());
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
        $priority = Zend_Log::CRIT;
        $this->view->error_code = $this->getResponse()->getHttpResponseCode();
        $this->view->message = 'Application error';
        if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
        $log->log($this->view->message, $priority, $errors->exception);
        $log->log('Request Parameters', $priority, $errors->request->getParams());
        $this->renderScript('error/error_500.phtml');
        }

    // conditionally display exceptions
        if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {
                $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
        }

        $this->view->request = $errors->request;
        $this->view->error_code = $this->getResponse()->getHttpResponseCode();
        $this->renderScript('error/error_500.phtml');
        break;
    }

    // Log exception, if logger available
    if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
      $log->log($this->view->message, $priority, $errors->exception);
      $log->log('Request Parameters', $priority, $errors->request->getParams());
    }

    // conditionally display exceptions
    if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {
      $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
    }

    $this->view->request = $errors->request;
  }

  public function getLog() {
    $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
    if (!$bootstrap->hasResource('Log')) {
      return false;
    }
    $log = $bootstrap->getResource('Log');
    return $log;
  }

}
```

Comment: just to confirm, Is above @KarmicDice code recommended/default way by Zend Framework? because for me content from $this->renderScript('error/error_404.phtml'); page is not loading unless I placed a die statement below the page.

Comment: I was a 'rockstar ZF 1x' guy... It's been around 1 year since I have touched it (after ZF2s launch). Am not sure... However, if it works only with a die script, it prolly means that you are rendering other page because when u perform $this->renderScript() it sends the header information already. Did u notice I have a `break;` ? and this function doesn't do anything else either.