# Zend redirect to controller if action not exist

Tags: php, zend-framework

For example I have action `example.com/books/list`

But I  made mistake and write `example.com/books/lists`, action `lists` not exist, how to redirect to `controller/index` if action not exist.

To check before go to action I can use **preDispatch()**, but how to check do this action exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to check weither an action exists or not. It takes as parameter `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract` and returns a `boolean` :

```
private function _actionExists($request) { 
            $dispatcher = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher(); 
            
            // Check controller 
            if (!$dispatcher->isDispatchable($request)) { 
                    return false; 
            } 
            
            // Check action 
            $controllerClassName = $dispatcher->formatControllerName( $request->getControllerName() ); 
            $controllerClassFile = $controllerClassName . '.php'; 
            if ($request->getModuleName() != $dispatcher->getDefaultModule()) { 
                    $controllerClassName = ucfirst($request->getModuleName()) . '_' . $controllerClassName; 
            } 
            try { 
                    require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; 
                    Zend_Loader::loadFile($controllerClassFile, $dispatcher->getControllerDirectory($request->getModuleName())); 
                    $actionMethodName = $dispatcher->formatActionName($request->getActionName()); 
                    if (in_array($actionMethodName, get_class_methods($controllerClassName))) { 
                            return true; 
                    } 
                    return false; 
            } catch(Exception $e) { 
                    return false; 
            } 
    }
```

Pleaser see this [link](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/should-isDispatchable-check-if-the-action-exists-td669352.html) for more details.

And then if the action effectively does not exists (the function returns false), redirect to your index route :

```
$this->_helper->redirector($action, $controller, $module);
```

**EDIT :**

AS @MuhannadA.Alhariri and @php-dev state respectively in their answer and comment, this can be also handled by customizing the `ErrorController` within we have just to compare the `error_handler` with `Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION`. Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286193/how-to-use-custom-404-page-on-not-found-controller-action?answertab=oldest#tab-top) which gives a customized error controller.

Comment: All you need is just compare error_handler type to `Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION` within your error controller :)

Answer (score 3):

Customize the error controller so that it redirects to 404 page or to do what ever behavior you want .

Comment: +1, Using error_handler object, and comparing type to `Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this piece of code

```
$classMethods = get_class_methods($className);
if(!in_array("__call", $classMethods) && !in_array($this->getActionMethod($request), $classMethods))
return false;
```